# Draw a panel control with a sunken look

Tags: beginner, vb.net, gui, graphics

I am relatively new to visual studio. I am in the process of creating a custom control and the same time learning. I have put together the beginning of this control and will love to get some input.

What this does is draw in a Panel Control so that it looks like the control has a inner bevel(sunken) on the form.

[image]

Although this seems to work, will I get some issues or is there a better way to do this? In the Bevel Class(Outer_Bevel) is not used yet.

```
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D




Public Class Carel_Scroll_Bar

    Inherits Windows.Forms.Control
    Public Wdth As Integer
    Dim Cntrl_Rail As New Child_Cntrls.Rail

    Public Sub New()

        Me.DoubleBuffered = True
        Me.Width = 50
        Me.Height = 500

        Me.Controls.Add(Cntrl_Rail)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Carel_Scroll_Bar_SizeChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.SizeChanged

        Dim Bev_Val As New Bevels

        Cntrl_Rail.Height = Me.Height
        Cntrl_Rail.Width = Me.Width
        Bev_Val.Cntrl_Hght = Me.Height
        Bev_Val.Cntrl_Wdth = Me.Width

    End Sub

End Class

Public Class Bevels

    Public In_Bev_Size = 5
    Public In_AO_Thick = 3
    Public Out_Bev_Size = 5
    Public Out_AO_Thick = 3
    Public Cntrl_Hght As Integer
    Public Cntrl_Wdth As Integer

    Public Sub Bevel_Inner(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)

        Dim clr1 As Color = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255)
        Dim clr2 As Color = Color.FromArgb(50, 0, 0, 0)
        Dim Bord As New Pen(Color.FromArgb(5, 0, 0, 0), In_AO_Thick)

        Dim Inn_01 As New Point(In_Bev_Size, In_Bev_Size)
        Dim Inn_02 As New Point(In_Bev_Size, Cntrl_Hght - In_Bev_Size)
        Dim Inn_03 As New Point(Cntrl_Wdth - In_Bev_Size, Cntrl_Hght - In_Bev_Size)
        Dim Inn_04 As New Point(Cntrl_Wdth - In_Bev_Size, In_Bev_Size)

        Dim Out_01 As New Point(0, 0)
        Dim Out_02 As New Point(0, Cntrl_Hght)
        Dim Out_03 As New Point(Cntrl_Wdth, Cntrl_Hght)
        Dim Out_04 As New Point(Cntrl_Wdth, 0)

        Dim Left_Grad As New Point(Cntrl_Wdth - In_Bev_Size, 0)
        Dim Right_Grad As New Point(In_Bev_Size, 0)
        Dim Top_Grad As New Point(0, In_Bev_Size)
        Dim Bot_Grad As New Point(0, Cntrl_Hght - In_Bev_Size)

        'Center
        Dim Cen_Pnts As Point() = {Inn_01, Inn_02, Inn_03, Inn_04}
        Dim Cen_Br As New SolidBrush(clr2)

        e.Graphics.FillPolygon(Cen_Br, Cen_Pnts)
        e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(Bord, Cen_Pnts)
        Cen_Br.Dispose()

        'Left
        Dim Left_Pnts As Point() = {Out_03, Out_04, Inn_04, Inn_03}
        Dim lef_Br As New LinearGradientBrush(Out_04, Left_Grad, clr1, clr2)

        e.Graphics.FillPolygon(lef_Br, Left_Pnts)
        e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(Bord, Left_Pnts)
        lef_Br.Dispose()

        'Right
        Dim Right_Pnts As Point() = {Out_01, Out_02, Inn_02, Inn_01}
        Dim Right_Br As New LinearGradientBrush(Out_01, Right_Grad, clr1, clr2)

        e.Graphics.FillPolygon(Right_Br, Right_Pnts)
        e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(Bord, Right_Pnts)
        Right_Br.Dispose()

        'Top
        Dim Top_Pnts As Point() = {Out_01, Out_04, Inn_04, Inn_01}
        Dim Top_Br As New LinearGradientBrush(Out_01, Top_Grad, clr1, clr2)

        e.Graphics.FillPolygon(Top_Br, Top_Pnts)
        e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(Bord, Top_Pnts)
        Top_Br.Dispose()

        'Bot
        Dim Bot_Pnts As Point() = {Out_02, Out_03, Inn_03, Inn_02}
        Dim Bot_Br As New LinearGradientBrush(Out_02, Bot_Grad, clr1, clr2)

        e.Graphics.FillPolygon(Bot_Br, Bot_Pnts)
        e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(Bord, Bot_Pnts)
        Bot_Br.Dispose()
        Bord.Dispose()

    End Sub
    Public Sub Bevel_Outer(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)

        Dim clr1 As Color = Color.FromArgb(50, 0, 0, 0)
        Dim clr2 As Color = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255)
        Dim Bord As New Pen(Color.FromArgb(5, 0, 0, 0), In_AO_Thick)

        Dim Inn_01 As New Point(Out_Bev_Size, Out_Bev_Size)
        Dim Inn_02 As New Point(Out_Bev_Size, Cntrl_Hght - Out_Bev_Size)
        Dim Inn_03 As New Point(Cntrl_Wdth - Out_Bev_Size, Cntrl_Hght - Out_Bev_Size)
        Dim Inn_04 As New Point(Cntrl_Wdth - Out_Bev_Size, Out_Bev_Size)

        Dim Out_01 As New Point(0, 0)
        Dim Out_02 As New Point(0, Cntrl_Hght)
        Dim Out_03 As New Point(Cntrl_Wdth, Cntrl_Hght)
        Dim Out_04 As New Point(Cntrl_Wdth, 0)

        Dim Left_Grad As New Point(Cntrl_Wdth - Out_Bev_Size, 0)
        Dim Right_Grad As New Point(Out_Bev_Size, 0)
        Dim Top_Grad As New Point(0, Out_Bev_Size)
        Dim Bot_Grad As New Point(0, Cntrl_Hght - Out_Bev_Size)

        'Center
        Dim Cen_Pnts As Point() = {Inn_01, Inn_02, Inn_03, Inn_04}
        Dim Cen_Br As New SolidBrush(clr2)

        e.Graphics.FillPolygon(Cen_Br, Cen_Pnts)
        e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(Bord, Cen_Pnts)
        Cen_Br.Dispose()

        'Left
        Dim Left_Pnts As Point() = {Out_03, Out_04, Inn_04, Inn_03}
        Dim lef_Br As New LinearGradientBrush(Out_04, Left_Grad, clr1, clr2)

        e.Graphics.FillPolygon(lef_Br, Left_Pnts)
        e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(Bord, Left_Pnts)
        lef_Br.Dispose()

        'Right
        Dim Right_Pnts As Point() = {Out_01, Out_02, Inn_02, Inn_01}
        Dim Right_Br As New LinearGradientBrush(Out_01, Right_Grad, clr1, clr2)

        e.Graphics.FillPolygon(Right_Br, Right_Pnts)
        e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(Bord, Right_Pnts)
        Right_Br.Dispose()

        'Top
        Dim Top_Pnts As Point() = {Out_01, Out_04, Inn_04, Inn_01}
        Dim Top_Br As New LinearGradientBrush(Out_01, Top_Grad, clr1, clr2)

        e.Graphics.FillPolygon(Top_Br, Top_Pnts)
        e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(Bord, Top_Pnts)
        Top_Br.Dispose()

        'Bot
        Dim Bot_Pnts As Point() = {Out_02, Out_03, Inn_03, Inn_02}
        Dim Bot_Br As New LinearGradientBrush(Out_02, Bot_Grad, clr1, clr2)

        e.Graphics.FillPolygon(Bot_Br, Bot_Pnts)
        e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(Bord, Bot_Pnts)
        Bot_Br.Dispose()
        Bord.Dispose()

    End Sub

End Class
Public Class Child_Cntrls


    Public Class Rail

        Inherits Windows.Forms.Panel

        Public Sub New()

            Me.DoubleBuffered = True
            'Me.BackColor = Color.Blue

        End Sub

        Private Sub Rail_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint

            Dim Bev_Val As New Bevels

            Bev_Val.Cntrl_Hght = Me.Height
            Bev_Val.Cntrl_Wdth = Me.Width
            Bev_Val.Bevel_Inner(e)

        End Sub

    End Class

End Class
```

The above code I used because I wanted to prevent stretching in my bevel and wanted my bevel size to stay the same when I resize my control. I tried the "PathGradientBrush()" before but it gave me the issues I mentioned. With a little research I managed to resolve this issue by using the "PathGradientBrush()" together with "FocusScales" and a "relativePositions".
With little calculations I manage to change the "FocusScales" values when I resize my control preventing the issues I mentioned.
The code is also a lot shorter and gives me the same effect as seen below.

[image]

```
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D

Public Class Control

  Inherits Windows.Forms.Panel

  Dim wdth As Integer
  Dim hght As Integer

Public Sub New()

    Me.DoubleBuffered = True
    Me.Width = 50
    Me.Height = 500

End Sub

Private Sub Control_SizeChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.SizeChanged

    wdth = Me.Width
    hght = Me.Height

End Sub

Private Sub Button_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint

    Bevel_Paint(e)

End Sub

Public Sub Bevel_Paint(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
    'Bevel size
    Dim bev = 5
    'Calculate Width Focus Scale for stretch prevension 
    'of the bevel when resizing the control
    Dim Width_bev = bev * 2 / wdth
    Dim Width_Scale = 1 - Width_bev
    'Calculate Height Focus Scale for stretch prevension 
    'of the bevel when resizing the control
    Dim Height_bev = bev * 2 / hght
    Dim Height_Scale = 1 - Height_bev
    'Main Rectangle Points
    Dim points As Point() = {New Point(0, 0),
                             New Point(wdth, 0),
                             New Point(wdth, hght),
                             New Point(0, hght)}
    'Gradient Brush
    Dim pthGrBrush As New PathGradientBrush(points)
    'Colors to use
    Dim colors As Color() = {Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255),
                             Color.FromArgb(50, 0, 0, 0)}
    'Set the position of the colors [0.0 = boundry][1.0 = center]
    Dim relativePositions As Single() = {0.0F, 1.0F}
    pthGrBrush.FocusScales = New PointF(Width_Scale, Height_Scale)

    Dim colorBlend As New ColorBlend()
    colorBlend.Colors = colors
    colorBlend.Positions = relativePositions
    pthGrBrush.InterpolationColors = colorBlend

    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(pthGrBrush, 0, 0, Me.Width, Me.Height)
    pthGrBrush.Dispose()

    'AO line rectangle to give a sharper look at the bottom sides
    Dim Rect As New Rectangle(bev, bev, wdth - (bev * 2), hght - (bev * 2))
    Dim My_Pen As New Pen(Color.FromArgb(10, 0, 0, 0), 3)

    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(My_Pen, Rect)
    My_Pen.Dispose()

End Sub

End Class
```

I would really love to get some input on this. Thanks.